# Visual studio loadtest run from VNext

Tags: tfs, load-testing, azure-pipelines

I have a visual studio loadTest project and LoadTest2010 result database, when I run the test from visual studio then test work fine and test data save in the LoadTest2010 DB but when run the test from VNext then test run fine (did all the configurations) but data does not save in the DB LoadTest2010.
In VNext VsoAgent agent is running the test.
Did any one face this issue?

Comment: What is "VNext"? The tag has no description, perhaps you could edit the tag to add its description.

Answer (score 0):

vNext is TFS Test Agent and it is VS2015 Test Agent, we ever used Test Controller and Test Agent for VS2013 Update5. vNext is Test Agent for VS2015.

According to your description, whether you have added a web test project in load test, if no, please make sure you have added it.
and then please use MSTest to run load test locally to see the results.

Answer (score 0):

What test steps do you use in your build definition? If you use the steps **Visual Studio Test Agent deployment** and **Run functional test** to run your load test, it may get the result like you posted above. Because these 2 steps are using VS Test agent 2015 and if you want to run load test, you need to install VS Test Agent 2013 according to [this document](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/lab-management/test-machines/install-configure-test-agents).

So about using the VS 2013 test agent in Vnext build, you could follow the step below:

- Add a test setting file for your test solution.
- Next, specify test controller and Load test result store in the setting file.
  [image]
- Then add a Visual Studio Test step in your build definition and in this step, remember to specify the testsetting file.

Comment: This is also not working as both  Visual Studio Test Agent deployment and Run functional test does not have option for loadtest file. Only the option is from command line but data will not save to loadtest database.

Answer (score 0):

this is the only one option right now in the VNext to run the loadtest and data will save to the loadtest database. Below is the snapshot from VNext  [image]